# Xamarin ListView Delete leaving gap when new item added

Tags: android, listview, xamarin.forms, menuitem

I have a ListView with a ViewCell action for deleting a row. In the delete action, I remove the row from the observable collection the listview is based on. This works OK, and the list shuffles up removing the deleted row. However, when I add a new item which takes you to a new page to define the details of the new item and then come back to the original page with the listview, the space for the row that was deleted has a gap where there should be an item. Indeed, the item is there because I can click on it and get taken to a new page to edit the item.

It seems as though the row is marked somehow to not show anything despite the fact there is a row of data to display and the row is active as I can click on it.

I thought IsDestructive might be causing a problem but have tried that as both True and False with no effect.

I have lots of listviews in the app and they are all behaving in the same way.

Any help much appreciated.

Here is the XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView" VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand" Grid.Column="1" ItemSelected="onItemSelection" SeparatorVisibility="None" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ViewCell>
                                                <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                                    <MenuItem Clicked="OnDelete"
                                                                        CommandParameter="{Binding EntryID}"
                                                                        Text="Delete" IsDestructive="False" />
                                                </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="10,1,0,0" Grid.Column="0">
                                                        <Label x:Name="inlineButton" Padding="10,7,20,7" Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}" BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}" Text="{Binding Subject}" TextColor="Black" IsVisible="True"/>
                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </ViewCell>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListView>
```

The Delete is fairly basic:

```
var mi = ((MenuItem)sender);
            var IDString = mi.CommandParameter.ToString();

            int ID = Int32.Parse(IDString);
            var item = selectedEvents.SingleOrDefault(x => x.EntryID == ID);

obsSelectedEvents.Remove(item);
```

And the OnAppearing sets up obsSelectedEvents (an ObservableCollection) and assigns it to the Listview:

```
 ListView.ItemsSource = obsSelectedEvents;
```

The ListViews works fine apart from when I delete an item and then immediately add another item. If I leave the page with the ListViews and come back to it the gap is no longer present.

Comment: without seeing the relevant code there is no way for us to help you

Comment: when you come back to the page with the ListView, is the OnAppearing firing again?

Comment: Yes, OnAppearing does fire so the obsSelectedEvents is set up again from the database with the new row added (and without the old row as it has been deleted from the database)

Comment: After 3 days, I appear to have fixed the problem. In the ListView I added: HasUnevenRows="false" RowHeight="40" and that seems to have fixed it, although I have no idea why